# Displaying the contents (rather than saving) of an uploaded file with Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

How can I have a form with a FileField, where the uploaded file will not be saved but instead its text contents will be extracted and displayed?

Answer (score 15):

Docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

Short version:

1. Your upload form needs to have a `forms.FileField` field.
2. When the form is submitted, it goes to a URL which goes to a view function you have written.  That view function takes an `HttpRequest` (usually named `request`).
3. Fetch the file from `request.FILES[]`.

For example, if your form has:

```
upFile = forms.FileField
```

Then your view can get to the file with:

```
def uploadView(request):
    upFile = request.FILES["upFile"]
```

where `upFile` is an `UploadedFile` object, which is *not* a file-like object.  An `UploadedFile` has the following properties:

- `name`: name of the uploaded file
- `size`: size in bytes

and the following methods:

- `read()`: Read the entire file and return as a string.  Probably good for you, but not recommended for files over 2.5 MB.
- `multiple_chunks()`: Returns `True` if the file should be handled as multiple chunks.
- `chunks()`: Returns a generator (use it like an iterator) which returns the file data one chunk at a time.

So, continuing the example, if you just wanted to save the file to disk, you could write:

```
outFile = open("/tmp/uploadTest.txt", "w")
if not upFile.multiple_chunks():
    outFile.write(upFile.read())
else:
    for chunk in upFile.chunks():
        outFile.write(chunk)
outFile.close()
```

In your case, you could probably just show an error message and discard the file if `multiple_chunks()` returns `True`, since you probably aren't looking to put over 2.5 MB of text on your page.

EDIT: Well, your question entirely changed while I was writing my answer.  So, spelling out how to put the file contents in the page, and assuming the file isn't over 2.5 MB, your view function could look like:

```
def uploadView(request):
    upFile = request.FILES["upFile"]
    context = {}
    if upFile.multiple_chunks():
        context["uploadError"] = "Uploaded file is too big (%.2f MB)." % (upFile.size,)
    else:
        context["uploadedFile"] = upFile.read()
    return render_to_response('fileUploadPage.html', context)
```

Adding, of course, whatever other view processing you need.

Then your `fileUploadPage.html` template needs to have somewhere:

```
<div id="uploaded">
    {% if uploadError %}
    <span class="error">{{ uploadError }}</span>
    {% else %}
    {{ uploadedFile }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

EDIT 2: Dominic has a good point.  Here's the generic template code for setting the `form` tag right.  Use this in the template that has the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url uploadFile %}"
{% if form.is_multipart %}
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
{% endif %}>
{{ form }}
</form>
```

In your case, since you know the form will have a file in it, you can lose the `if` block:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url uploadFile %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ form }}
</form>
```

Note: The `{% url ___ %}` command will put in the URL for a view or named URL.  The parameter is either the name of the view function as used in your `urls.py` file, or the name given to the `url` object, like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^uploadform$', 'myapp.views.uploadFormView', name='uploadForm'),
    url('^upload$', 'myapp.views.uploadView', name='uploadFile'),
    # ...
)
```

Comment: Can you add something in about `enctype` on the `<form>` tag? Save the OP running into trouble!

Comment: @Mike D. - I rewrote the question - I don't *think* I changed the meaning, just hopefully made it easier to parse.

Comment: Like so many projects, it started out small... but grew... ;_;  And it's still short compared to the web page I referenced in he first line.

Comment: What if the file was an image?  What would I set the context object to so that I can specify the src attribute of an <img> tag?